# Serializable field in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little question, if someone can help me, I'll be grateful.

> What is Serializable field in Unity ?

> How it works for an object of a class ?

In code it's looks like :

```
[Serializable]
```

or

```
[System.Serializable]
```

Comment: Feed your title to Google *et voila!*: [Why should I use SerializeField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192019/why-should-i-use-serializefield)

Comment: It means...you'll never believe this...the class can be serialized!  [Just like the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: `[Serializable]` just means that you can edit something in the inspector if you are talking about unity. `[System.Serializable]` is something else. Go check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Serializable]
private GameObject gameobject;

[System.Serializable]
private int timer;

The serializable field works like a public variable except that you can using it for a private variable. Some people just use a public variable but a serializable private variable works the same.

Answer (score -2):

Might be a lazy answer... but Unity provides a very useful documentation (with examples) which explains every command, even [Serializable].

Here is the link to what you are looking for:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html